Error MSB4018 "ResolvePackageAssets" task failed unexpectedly in .NET Project
I've tried to build a .NET project(with ABP framework), but I encountered the following error message. I'm not sure what the issue is or how to solve it.
I'm working with :
.NET SDK Version 8.0
Visual Studio Version 2022
The Error message:
Error   MSB4018 The "ResolvePackageAssets" task failed unexpectedly.
NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackagingException: Unable to find fallback package folder 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\NuGetPackages'.
at NuGet.Packaging.FallbackPackagePathResolver..ctor(String userPackageFolder, IEnumerable`1 fallbackPackageFolders)
at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.NuGetPackageResolver.CreateResolver(IEnumerable`1 packageFolders)
at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheWriter..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task)
at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader.CreateReaderFromDisk(ResolvePackageAssets task, Byte[] settingsHash)
at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task)
at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ReadItemGroups()
at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ExecuteCore()
at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()    App.IdentityServer  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.204\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets    266```


I've checked the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared' and there's no "NuGetPackages" folder in it.
And I've tried cleaning and rebuilding the project.
But nothing works


Try the following: Run a Clean, delete the obj and bin directories in the project directory, run a Restore, and then run a Build. (In Visual Studio you can run a restore by right-clicking the solution in the solution explorer and choosing "Restore NuGet Packages".)
